# Why is my Docx converter returning 'None'

Tags: python, django, pdf, ms-word, pywin32

I am new to web development and trying to create a language translation app in Django that translates uploaded documents. It relies on a series of interconversions between pdf and docx. When my code ouputs the translated document it cannot be opened.

1. When I inspect the file type I saw it identified as XML and docx and it could be opened and read by MS Word when I changed the extension to docx(But it couldn't be read by any PDF readers).
2. When I used my code python to analyze the file by printing the type and the contents of it I got NoneType and None.
3. A working PDF of the file is found in mysite/mysite folder but the one output by my reConverter function that is sent to the browser is the problem file.
4. I tried manually converting it using:

```
wordObj = win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application')
docObj = wordObj.Documents.Open(wordFilename)
docObj.SaveAs(pdfFilename, FileFormat=wdFormatPDF)
docObj.Close()
wordObj.Quit()
```

but got a CoInitialization error. My original
So I've completely narrowed it down to the reConverter function returning a NoneType.
Here is my code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from .models import TranslatedDocument
from .forms import UploadFileForm
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
import docx
from pdf2docx import parse
from docx2pdf import convert
import time #remove


# Create your views here.

#pythoncom.CoInitialize()
@csrf_protect
def translateFile(request) :
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            uploaded_file = request.FILES['file']
            fs = FileSystemStorage()
            filename = fs.save(uploaded_file.name, uploaded_file)
            uploaded_file_path = fs.path(filename)

            file = (converter(uploaded_file_path))
        response = HttpResponse(file, content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="' + filename + '"'
        return response
    
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'translator_upload/upload.html', {'form': form})


def reConverter(inputDocxPath):
    #reconvert docx to pdf
    
    print('reConverter: '+str(inputDocxPath))
    outputPdfPath = inputDocxPath.replace('.docx', '.pdf')
    test = convert(inputDocxPath, outputPdfPath)
    print(type(test))
    print('test: '+str(test))
    return test

def translateDocx(aDocx, stringOfDocPath):
    #translation logic
    docx_file = stringOfDocPath
    myDoc = docx.Document(docx_file)
    print('translateDocx: '+str(docx_file))
    print('translateDocx: '+str(myDoc))
    for paragraphNum in range(len(myDoc.paragraphs)):

    #TRANSLATION LOGIC


    myDoc.save(docx_file)
    return reConverter(docx_file)


    
#stringOfDocPath is used as convert() requires file path, not file object(myDoc)

def converter(inputPdfPath):
    # convert pdf to docx
    
    pdf_file = inputPdfPath
    docx_file = inputPdfPath.replace('.pdf', '.docx')
    print('file types saved: '+docx_file+'. Converting to docx')


    parse(pdf_file, docx_file) #,  start=0, end=3)
    myDoc = docx.Document(docx_file)
    print('converter '+str(myDoc))
    return translateDocx(myDoc, docx_file)
```

Comment: `docx2pdf.convert` really returns `None`, as can be seen from the [source code](https://github.com/AlJohri/docx2pdf/blob/master/docx2pdf/__init__.py). What return value are you expecting? (and please, follow python naming convention in python code, it makes your code readable for other people: variables and functions should be named in `snake_case`, not `camelCase`)

Comment: @STerliakov Hi. I'm trying to return the converted(PDF) file to the user.

Comment: @KJ I have Word and Adobe installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

docx2pdf.convert always return 'None'

The converted pdf file is saved to the 'outputPdfPath' file.

In order to show the pdf file to the user, you must read the pdf file from the 'outputPdfPath'.

```py
def reConverter(inputDocxPath):
    #reconvert docx to pdf
    
    print('reConverter: '+str(inputDocxPath))
    outputPdfPath = inputDocxPath.replace('.docx', '.pdf')
    convert(inputDocxPath, outputPdfPath)
    with open(outputPdfPath, "r") as f:
        test = f.read()
    print(type(test))
    print('test: '+str(test))
    return test
```

Comment: @This works. Appreciate.